# How can we find if a matrix is full column rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an $n*k$ matrix with complicated form of elements. How can I show this matrix is full column rank?

By complicated form I mean there is no known form for the elements of $A$.

Comment: I have checked almost all the result to show $A$ is full column rank but it is not easy to show them, for example all following result I have checked:  i) $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$.  ii) Matrix $A^TA$ is positive definite or it is singular.  iii) A has right inverse  and so on...

Comment: Can you describe the matrix as explicitly as possible?

Comment: The $ik$th element of that matrix is a in the form of $\sum_j a_{ijk}p_j$ such that $a_{ijk}$ is a known coefficient and $p_i$ is a fixed probability.

Answer (score 1):

Use your point ii). Here $k\leq n$.

Step 1. The calculation of  $B=A^TA$ has complexity $\sim nk^2$.

Step 2. Apply Choleski algorithm to $B$. If it works, then $B>0$, otherwise, it is not. Its complexity is $\sim k^3/3$.

Finally, the total complexity is $\sim nk^2+k^3/3\leq (4/3)n^3$.

EDIT. 1. During STEP 2, we can also calculate $\det(B)$; if it is not $0$, then $B>0$, otherwise it is not; the complexity is a bit superior: $\sim (2/3)k^3$.

2. Practically, both methods (used in STEP 2) are unstable. The previous complexities stand when the coefficients are represented by floating point numbers; in such conditions, how to be sure that $\det(B)=0$ ? If you know an estimation of the error, then you can (often) prove that $\det(B)\not =0$. If you want to show that $\det(B)=0$, then you must do an exact calculation. For instance, assume that the entries of $A$ are integers. Then the complexity of the calculation of $\det(B)$, by  the most effective method, is: $(n^{3.2}\log(||B||))^{1+o(1)}$, where $||B||$ denotes the largest entry of $B$.

   cf http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gilles.villard/BIBLIOGRAPHIE/PDF/KaVi04.pdf

Comment: Calculating matrix $B$ is not an easy task, even though, how can I use Cholesky decomposition when I have no idea that $B$ is positive definite? In fact $B$ being positive definite is my goal.

Comment: You can apply the Cholesky algorithm to any symmetric matrix. During each step of the process, you calculate the square root of a number; this number must be $>0$;. If this number is $\leq 0$, then you stop the process. .

Comment: ok, Thank you, but still I can not understand what do you mean by "Apply Choleski algorithm to $B$. If it works, then $B>0$." What do you mean by if it works? Do you mean if decomposition is possible?

Comment: Of course you mentioned if $det(B)$ non zero it means $B>0$, but the issue is calculating determinant is almost impossible.